# How to fetch single value from the array in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am  getting the data from the user which is stored in one variable called `$data`.what my api is doing if i pass route url it should be displayed all books.if i pass query params as `search=BookName` it fetches the details of the particular searchable bookname

```
$data=request->all();
public function run(Array $data){
 if($data){
            if(!is_null($data['search'])){
                //it will execute
            }
            else
            return this code;
        }
}
```

what's my problem is if i hit api along with **?search=Book1** ,it's working fine .but if run without  any **search** it's throwing an error ,please help me to fix the issue..

**Error**

`Undefined index: search`

Comment: did you tried $data->search? or what kind of data you're getting inside $data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data=request->all();

public function run(Array $data){
$Search =  $data['search'] ?? null;
 if($data){
            if($Search){
                //it will execute
            }
            else
      return // something;
   }
}
```

Here simply the `$search` is storing the value of `$data['search']` so if there no value/key exists in `$data['search']`  we just store `null`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but can you give some idea  what `$search` is doing ..?